# How to move my form when on screen keyboard is shown

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, soft-keyboard

Im trying some different alternatives for onscreen keyboard for our desktop application that is being run on a windows 8 tablet without keyboard.
So far Tabtip.exe have been working best but im open to other solutions.

The problem i have is when the user clicks on a textbox in the application and i show the onscreen keyboard, the keyboard hides the textbox.
How do fix this in a good way?
Is it something that windows can handle automatically? Some applications like outlook and word gets a "splitscreen" with a scroll bar in the upper part where the applications is and the keyboard in the lower part. I want a solution like that to. How do they do it?

One solution could be to always move my window up a set amount of pixels that is the same as the keyboard height. But i don't want to move the application if the keyboard doesn't cover the textbox.
But how do i determine how high the keyboard is? is it always the same height? How do i detect where the window is?

Any other solutions?